# How to represent the gates and the quibit states in the 'Hello Quantum' iOS game in IBM Quantum Learning graphical simulator

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, ibm-q-experience, qasm

The Hello Quantum ios game developed by IBM has the X, Z, H and CZ gates manipulating a 2 qubit array (im not sure if array is the right word?).

I want to know how I can represent the qubit states in the game in the IBM quantum learning simulator.

Specifically

a) how can I represent the starting state in the iPhone screenshot in the quantum learning graphical simulator?

b) how can I then apply the rules/gates (eg. gate xyz on qubit[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2j42O.jpg), then gate abc on qubit[0]) to this starting state to the target state as specified in the screenshot below, in the quantum learning simulator?

c) how do i know if i've done this correctly or not, without having to manually check the sequence of the gates in the app?

I have attached screenshot of the ios game setup and the IBM quantum learning environment to this.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.